# How to parse map[string]interface{}

Tags: go

I am unable to parse json that has string keys and array as value ending up with `json: Unmarshal(non-pointer map[string]interface {})` error.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var s map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte("{\"a\":[1,2,3]}"), s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Nice parse!")
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/AXlF8I-f9-p

Comment: Pass `&s` to `Unmarshal`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unmarshal parses the JSON-encoded data and stores the result in the value pointed to by v. If v is nil or not a pointer, Unmarshal returns an InvalidUnmarshalError. Add &s as a parameter

```
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte("{\"a\":[1,2,3]}"), &s)
```